# Have a list overflow into another column only when there's no room left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dynamically created list that's added to a webpage whenever the user clicks a button. Sometimes the list is short, which is fine, but sometimes it's long and it flows off the bottom of the page. How do I make it so that any overflow will instead create a new column? (I don't want the columns to be even in length- I want the first column to be used for as much of the text as possible, and the next column only used when the first one runs out of room.)

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce a list of items to a list of columns of items (array of arrays). Then use this to render the html:

```js
var longList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
var htmlList = function(list){
  return "<ul>" +
    list.map(
      function(listItem){
        return "<li>"+listItem+"</li>";
      }
    ).join("")
    +"</ul>"
}
var htmlColums = function(listOfList){
  return listOfList.map(
    function(list){
      return "<div style='float:left'>" +
        htmlList(list) +
        "</div>";
    }
  ).join("");
}
//takes a list of items and returns a list of list items 
//  list of columns
var toColumns = function(list,itemsInColumn){
  return list.reduce(
    function(acc,item){
      if(acc.slice(-1)[0].length===itemsInColumn){
        acc.push([])
      }
      acc.slice(-1)[0].push(item);
      return acc;
    }
    ,[[]]
  )
};

document.getElementById("createContent").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(e){
    var itemsInColumn = parseInt(
      document.getElementById("itemsInColumn").value
      ,10
    );
    if(isNaN(itemsInColumn)){
      itemsInColumn=3;
    }
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = htmlColums(
      toColumns(longList,itemsInColumn)
    );
    
  }
)
```

```html
    <input type="number" placeholder="Items in column" id="itemsInColumn">
    <input type="button" value="render items" id="createContent">
    <div id="content">
```